# Knockout JS ASP.NET MVC C# Model Make Observable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, model

I have a list of JSON models that I'm receiving from the server via AJAX.

I don't want to have to redefine my models as functions in JavaScript as well.

How can I prevent having to do below? I still want all the model properties to be observable though.

```
function Car(car) {

    this.Name = ko.observable(car.Name);
    this.Type = ko.observable(car.Type);
    this.Rating = ko.observable(car.Rating);
    this.Color = ko.observable(car.Color);
}

var ViewModel = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.cars = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.post('/car/getall', function (cars) {

        var carsKO= [];
        $.each(cars, function (i, elm) {

            carsKO.push(new Car(elm));
        });

        self.cars(carsKO);
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

People are talking about Knockout Mapping plugin. But I fail to see how that would get me any different than below? At this point I wouldn't have the model properties observable.

```
var ViewModel = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.cars = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.post('/car/getall', function (cars) {

        self.cars(cars);
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: In your example I don't see the usage of the ko.mapping plugin... I guess you wanted to wrote:  `$.post('/car/getall', function (cars) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(cars, {}, self.cars);
        });`...

Comment: don't call the mapping plugin on the array. loop the array calling the mapping plugin and push to your observableArray. There currently is no built in solution for this. However if you do not care about the values changing other than the physical collection itself, there is no need to observe the properties at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the fromJS function of [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) like this :

```
var ViewModel = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.cars = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.post('/car/getall', function (cars) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(cars, {}, self.cars);
    });
};
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Don't depend completely on it as it's still flawed. Consider you have an array of { id: 1, name: 'john', gender: { id: 1, name: 'male' }}. The results will be id and name as observable but gender will be Object who has an id and name that is observable. Replacing gender as an object is NOT observed. Haven't run a test on sub arrays yet, but I have a feeling they will act similarly.